# How to make listview selected one item element?

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I am working on the custom Listview using BaseAdapter. I am facing one small issue after tap on listview item that particular row gets highlighted but after that if i'll tap one another list item it's highlighted but still the older one it remains same it's not going to it's previous state.

I want to see one item should select at one time.

[image]

MainActivity.java

```
if (musicRealmResults.get(currentIndex).isSelected() == false) {
    musicRealmResults.get(currentIndex).setIsSelected(true);

    playSong(currentIndex, true);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
} else {
    musicRealmResults.get(currentIndex).setIsSelected(false);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

MusicAdapter.java

```
if (musicRealmResults.get(position).isSelected()) {

    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/fonts_bold.otf");
    holder1.albumsTextView.setTypeface(tf);

    holder1.equalizerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder1.albumsImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    holder1.equalizerView.animateBars();
} else {
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/fonts_regular.otf");
    holder1.albumsTextView.setTypeface(tf);

    holder1.equalizerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder1.albumsImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder1.equalizerView.stopBars();
}
```

Please kindly go through my post and suggest me how to do select and deselect in a listview row.

Comment: In your OnItemClickListener of listview. Set the boolean(isSelected) of particular position true and rest false. and notifyDataSetChanged. Then in your Adapter getview() , according to that flag change color and font etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manage this in your `model class`. Just make a toggle `Boolean isSelected` with its `getter and setter`, When user tap on list item check whether its already selected or not, if not then mark it as selected and update the Boolean value in your model class.

```
mListLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(list.get(position).getisSelected()){
                    // list item is already selected.
                    mListLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);  // normal color
                    list.get(position).setisSelected(false);
                }
                else{
                    // list item is not selected, make it selected
                    mListLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);  // selected color
                    list.get(position).setisSelected(true);
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you weren't able to `setSelected(false)` your previous item.
Please check `setChoiceMode()` of `ListView` or you may just reset your previous item to `setSelected(false)`.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { 
    musicRealmResults.get(currentSelected).setIsSelected(false); //Reset previous
     currentSelected = position; //Save currentPosition to for reset later
    .....todos
}
```

Comment: hey thanks can you tell me how to do in OnItemClickListener ?

Comment: If `setChoiceMode()` doesn't work for you, you can keep track of currentSelectedIndex/position in `onItemClick`, then get the previous selectedIndex the set it to false in `onItemClick()`

Answer (score 1):

Loop through all your array elements and set check state to false, then set `currentIndex`  to true.

`MainActivity`

```
for(int i =0 ; i < musicRealmResults.size() ; ++i){
   musicRealmResults.get(i).setIsSelected(false);
}

musicRealmResults.get(currentIndex).setIsSelected(true);

playSong(currentIndex, true);

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: hey thanks i don't think it's a good idea if the arraylist size is more then the ui becomes slow.

Comment: Looping all items just to set a single index is not a good idea. Not a good Programming practice though.

Comment: @ekouChiq with today CPUs is no problem

Answer (score 1):

This is a good alternative too, if u dont want to loop through the rest of positions to deselect them.

```
int prevSelection =-1; //nothing selected

listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (prevSelection==-1) //nothing selected
                    { 
                      musicRealmResults.get(position).setIsSelected(true);
                      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                      prevSelection = position;
                   }else if (prevSelection == position) //deselect previously selected
                   {
                    musicRealmResults.get(position).setIsSelected(false);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    prevSelection = -1;
               }else // Some other selection
                  {
                  musicRealmResults.get(prevSelection).setIsSelected(false);
                   musicRealmResults.get(position).setIsSelected(true);
                  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                  prevSelection = position;
}
```

Comment: @D Agrawal hey thanks but i am getting this exception "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: rowIndex is less than 0.", musicRealmResults.get(prevSelection).setIsSelected(false); in this line

Comment: int prevSelection  = -1  should  be above ur onCreate(); with other varaible declarations. And also my mistake first condition should be if(prevSelection == -1) . Ill update.

Comment: Cool, Happy to help. !!

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code:

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
        {
           if (musicRealmResults.get(position).isSelected() == false)
           {
              musicRealmResults.get(position).setIsSelected(true);

              playSong(position, true);

              adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           }
           else 
           {
              musicRealmResults.get(position).setIsSelected(false);
              adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           }

        }
    });
```